# Repeatable pattern within String?

Tags: regex, python-2.7, pattern-matching, suffix-tree

I want to write a function in Python which can detect repeatable pattern within the given String.

**Note**: Pattern is not given as Input.

**Example**: "//sample prograe program"

**Output**: Location = 7 Pattern = "e progra"

Comment: You cannot solve that with regex, but you've correctly identified the problem - you'll need a suffix tree and there are a couple of competent Python modules that do just that: [`sufix-trees`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/suffix-trees/0.2.3) as a generalized solution, and [`sufix_tree`](http://www.daimi.au.dk/%7Emailund/suffix_tree.html) as a C-backed one if you're looking for maximum efficiency.

Comment: @zwer Thanks for giving the lead. But the problem is I do not have any pattern to search in given String. I need to search the pattern in the String itself. Can you please let me know how to do that?